# Trouble with Azure IoT C# SDK Certificate

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-suite

I am receiving this error when I try to connect to Azure IoT Hub. Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.UnauthorizedException.

I could not post the error screen shots here, since I do not have enough reputation points.
So instead I wrote the whole details at
http://azuregeon.blogspot.in/2017/10/azure-iot-c-certificate-connectivity.html

if anyone gets a chance please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the Common Name as "_demoDevice" when authenticating you x.509 device. The Common Name is used to identify this certificate in the Azure web interface.In addition, the operation will be more simple and precise based on the official documationation([PowerShell scripts to manage CA-signed X.509 certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-create-certificates#signverificationcode)).
[image]